# How did the romance languages' feminine/masculine genders develop?

Tags: etymology, nouns, gender

How did French, Spanish, Italian, end up with gendered nouns?

The [Wikipedia page *Proto-Indo-European nominals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_nominals#Gender) says

> Originally, there probably were only an animate (masculine/feminine) and an inanimate (neuter) gender.

I have heard that the animate gender split into masculine and feminine genders.

> Grammatical gender correlates only partially with sex... Even then, those correlations may not be consistent

Why did these languages develop masculine and feminine genders for their nouns? Why was that useful for the language users? How did the correlations between two classes of nouns and the two sexes arise?

Comment: They didn’t. The masculine/feminine split happened within Core Indo-European; it was completely fixed and established by the time of Latin and is shared with lots and lots of other IE branches (Celtic, Germanic, Greek, Balto-Slavic, Indo-Iranian, etc.). The Romance languages _lost_ the neuter gender but didn’t develop any new genders of their own.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would like to know how the noun genders that are found in modern romance languages came into existence.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don’t _really_ know. The Wikipedia page you link to in the question describes what is generally assumed to have happened quite well, and that’s about all we can really say. ‘Why’ is rarely a question that can be answered meaningfully in language change. Also remember that ‘masculine’ and ‘feminine’ are terms applied by later linguists; the people in whose speech they developed likely didn’t have any such notion of them at all once they stopped being made up of recognisable feminising suffixes (like _-ess_ in English).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Romanian still keeps the three-gender system, but it's different from the Latin gender system: Romanian neuter gender nouns are declined like masculine nouns in singular and how feminine nouns in plural.

Comment: @YellowSky Romanian has been argued to have only m and f as well, though the traditional view includes n; a similar case can also be made that Italian has three genders (though more vestigially). When I said ‘Romance languages’ above, I meant more specifically ‘the Romance languages that have lost (or are analysed as having lost) the neuter’.

Comment: @YellowSky: It's also been argued that Romanian lost the three-gender system and then gained it again. Or that the current system that's called a three-gender system isn't really a three-gender system. It does have three noun classes, but neuter is just the name given to the class that maps with the other two classes split by whether it's in the singular or plural. It's really nothing like the three-gender systems of German, Greek, Slavic, or Latin.

Comment: @hippietrail - That can well be the case, that's why I wrote "it's _different_ from the Latin gender system", Romanian doesn't even have a neuter gender 3rd p. sg. personal pronoun. But just note that AFAIK it's only the neuter gender nouns that have the plural suffix _-uri_ in Romanian, correct me, please, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @YellowSky: Actually my Romanian is very basic and rusty. Had to leave Romania because of the COVID situation over a year ago )-: But it's an intriguing language.

Comment: A highly recommended book which has answers for all of your questions about genders in the Romance languages, PDF, 6 MB: [“Gender from Latin to Romance: History, Geography, Typology”, Oxford University Press, 2018, Michele Loporcaro](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10gn1pj9667FI_0apJg9zcBCFCiiM87GE/view?usp=sharing).